Google Scholar sort by date returns less results
I am using https://serpapi.com/ to scrape publications from google scholar.
When I sort by relevance I get more publications then when I sort by date (Include everything).
Any idea why this might happen? Is there any solution how to handle this particular occasions?
I tried to investigate but no success

You're right, when sort by date, there are less publications. Unfortunately, that seem to be how Google Scholar works. There are similar questions on the web (ref), this answer might make sense.

This is probably related to SEO associated with the .pdf file or webpage. These are basically "hidden metadata" used by Google to index its pages and know in which research by the user it should appear. If it has a date, Google will index it on "sort by date" by ascending order. If not, it will be excluded from this filter, as he cannot rank lack of information.

